# Getting the row with the lowest value for a variable in a dataframe of triads

Tags: r

i would like to filter this table in a specific way so that for each triad of values for variable A, B and C, i get the one with the lowest level for factor variable D. i show an example:

```
sof7 <- structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "tomato", class = "factor"), B = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("mozzarella", 
"salami", "zucchini"), class = "factor"), C = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L), D = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

expected:

```
A   B   C   D
tomato  zucchini    2   A1
tomato  mozzarella  1   A2
tomato  salami  5   A2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `slice` on a numeric index after grouping by 'A', 'B'

```
library(dplyr)
sof7 %>% 
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    slice(which.min(C))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   A, B [3]
#  A      B              C D    
#  <fct>  <fct>      <int> <fct>
#1 tomato mozzarella     1 A2   
#2 tomato salami         5 A2   
#3 tomato zucchini       2 A1
```

---

Or using `filter`

```
sof7 %>%
     group_by(A, B) %>%
     filter(C == min(C))
```

---

Or if it is to do the grouping by 'A', 'B', 'C' and get the row with the lowest `level` for the `factor` variable 'D'

```
sof7 %>%
    group_by(A, B, C) %>% 
    slice(which.min(D))
```

Comment: the variable im interested is D, is that considered numeric as well?

Comment: @mightaskalot. Here, we are sliciing the rows so that which ever row is the minimum for 'C' after groupinig by 'A', 'B', it will filter/slice that row.  From your expected output, I see. all the columns of the original dataset are returned.  If you check the code, I am not using `D`

Comment: @mightaskalot Can you please tell me what your expected output is

Comment: hey thanks a lot, its the first time i see the slice() function. What's that supposed to mean? I really don't care about variable C, want to sort each triad (A,B,C) based on D. I don't understand.

Comment: @mightaskalot. `D` is a `factor` variable.  If you meant to sort based on the minimum level?

Comment: Yes indeed. In my data each triad can potentially have a D level ranging from A1 to A5. And for each triad i want to keep the minimum A.

Comment: @mightaskalot In your post, it says `get the one with the lowest variable D.`. I updated the post based on that description